# use of $this inside the symfony2 QueryBuilder

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have the following code.

```
 $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
                ->add('distributor', 'entity', array(
                    'class' => 'AdminBundle:Customers',
                    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $repository) {
                        return $repository->createQueryBuilder('c')
                                ->where('c.customerType =:type')
                                ->Andwhere('c.status =:status')
                                ->andWhere('c.district =:district')
                                ->setparameter('status', '1')
                                ->setparameter('type', '1')
                                ->setparameter('district', $this->get("security.context")->getToken()->getUser()->getCustomer()->getDistrict()->getId())
                        ;
                    },
                    'property' => 'customerName',
                    'empty_value' => 'Select Distributor',
                    'multiple' => FALSE,
                    'expanded' => FALSE,
                    'required' => TRUE,
                        )
                )
                ->add('excel_file', 'file'
                ->getForm();
```

When I am going to use distributor element in the twig like this

```
 {{ form_widget(form.distributor,{ 'attr': {'class': 'input-box'} }) }}
```

it is getting an error...
***Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context***

How to use $this in the symfony QueryBuilder with form?

Thanks
Rakhitha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably using PHP 5.3, and thus you cannot use `$this` in a closure. To fix this issue, do the following:

```
 $id = $this->get("security.context")->getToken()->getUser()->getCustomer()->getDistrict()->getId();
 $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
                ->add('distributor', 'entity', array(
                    'class' => 'AdminBundle:Customers',
                    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $repository) use ($id) {
                        return $repository->createQueryBuilder('c')
                                ->where('c.customerType =:type')
                                ->Andwhere('c.status =:status')
                                ->andWhere('c.district =:district')
                                ->setparameter('status', '1')
                                ->setparameter('type', '1')
                                ->setparameter('district', $id)
                        ;
                    },
                    'property' => 'customerName',
                    'empty_value' => 'Select Distributor',
                    'multiple' => FALSE,
                    'expanded' => FALSE,
                    'required' => TRUE,
                        )
                )
                ->add('excel_file', 'file'
                ->getForm();
```

Comment: Hi Dennis,
Thanks for the quick reply and I have already tried this and it says id is a undefined variable.

Comment: It's impossible. Did you notice `use ($id)` in the closure?